# XDebug or Zend Debugger?

Tags: php, debugging

It seems to me that they have both the same function set, but I'm not sure.

What are the differences in functionality between the two?

Comment: It seems PHPStorm uses both XDebug and Zend Debugger.

Answer (score 9):

Zend debugger is only available in binary format, so you need to be careful to download the right version to match your version of php ( http://downloads.zend.com/pdt/server-debugger/ ). I was able to get it working with Eclipse PDT and do line-by-line debugging with a local XAMPP installation. I think Zend has some additional features, but in my experience it has been easier to set up.

XDebug is much more open, but I haven't successfully configured it to work with Eclipse PDT.

Comment: Since PHP 5.4 a separate download for the Zend Debugger is no longer available from Zend. You need to download the Free Zend Server, that comes with the zend extension. You can copy the extension into your own PHP configuration.

Comment: Bart’s comment is not the case: for PHP 5.4, 5.5, and 5.6 binary packages of debugger are available.

Comment: It's been 8 years and still the *difference in functionality* between these two is a mystery. ;)

Comment: @BartVerkoeijen Zend Server is not free

Answer (score 6):

XDebug works with Eclipse and with Netbeans (and some other ide's).

ZendDebug doesn't work with Netbeans.
ZendDebug is already configured in ZendServer.

Comment: @MauganRa PhpStorm has configuration settings for Zend Debug. But I've never tried it.